# How to specify wild card (*) to apply color to all child (deep level) using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have one `<div id='sample'></div>` and I would like to apply `color` css property to all its children (means at all depth level).

When I do from css like

```
#sample * {
    color: '#AAA'
}
```

it applies proper color but I am not able to do this using jQuery when page is ready.

I wanted to do this because I would like to switch color based on `radio` button clicked.

Can any one help me?

**Why downvoted?**

Comment: I'd prefer to intially set color of the children to transparent. then just change parent color. its easier

Comment: You should have provided in question your failed attempt

Comment: See the second example in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/

Comment: Why the wrong answer gets the most votes? Are we looking for the fanciest way of writing something as simple as `$('#sample *').css('color', '#AAA');`? If OP wants `#sample *`, than that's what he should get...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#sample *').css('color', '#AAA');
```

Tested and works. http://jsfiddle.net/2e8wp/

But a complete CSS approach might be a better idea.

Comment: Hi @Shomz, I agree with you answer but I have requirement to apply color based on radio button clicked.

Comment: Hi, you can read off the radio values and pick the color according to it (like `var colors = {gray: '#AAA'...};`)... However, the CSS approach I suggested might be better because you'd only have to change the class of one of the top elements and let CSS handle the rest. With the JS way... you're basically adding inline styles to every element which is rarely a good idea. But choose whatever works best for your app.

Comment: Your CSS suggestion I thought previously but then I have to create two different classes, right?

Comment: Yes, ideally one class for each radio button.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use the children() JQuery method.

```
$('#sample').children().css('color', '#AAA');
```

That will set css for its children, but if you have inline styles/classes within the parents that set the color - it will not overwrite them, see one of the `.find('*')` solutions for that functionality...

http://jsfiddle.net/H7zL5/
here is an example of what I mean..

Comment: He wants all descendants, regardless of depth.

Comment: .children() will only get the first descendants.

Comment: I guess this is the best approach because anyway color is inherited for any other descendants. But then, you could set color on '#sample'. But i'm not sure this is what OP is looking for

Comment: @A.Wolff Ah that's true, but it could be that the descendants have a color style themselves like this http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/L5SJz/

Comment: @Anton ya, but i think OP question is indeed an XY problem, looks like it to me

Comment: style will cascade unless overwritten.. should I remove this answer? @A.Wolff

Comment: @JFit keep it, it's still a valid answer imo.

Comment: For example, it won't affect any anchors that are indirect descendants... http://jsfiddle.net/H7zL5/1/

Comment: @Shomz that's a good example of kind of exception! Thx for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Use `.find('*');`

```
$('#sample').find('*').css('color','#AAA');
```

Comment: Why not just use one selector?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

Add a css rule:

```
#sample.active * { color: #AAA }
```

Then when appropriate:

```
$('#sample').addClass('active');
```